# Copy and edit an .ini file when building a C# visual studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, copy, config

I have two projects that use each other.
one project is an environment which can run sub projects from the kind of the other project.

so this environment project can be upgrade with the time...
and I created a template for the sub project that creates a project with all the necessery settings and files so when it builds it copies the files from the environment project and create an all together build to run the sub project with the environment.

what i want to do is when building the sub project file (the one that was created from the template) copy all the files from the environment project's build and change the config.ini file i copied from there so it will fit the configuration for the new project i built.

bottom line:
I want to copy a file from a known path during the build of a project. The tricky part is that I want to edit this file (I can put $variables$ inside the source .ini file and change them during the build - like I do with the project template).

I really been searching for few days for solution to this problem and couldn't find a suitable one.

thank you for your help!

Yair

Comment: please explain  "building the sub project file ". What does building refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use "post build step" in the project to run whatever exe's or batch commands you need after the build.

Comment: BTW: in order to run .exe file in post build event just go to your project properties to the "build events" tab and just add the command line as you would write it in the command prompt. thanks